# How to convert the the column Time nanoseconds with object data type to datetime?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime, types

I have the below dataset in "object datatype" . I want to change the datatype to datetime.

```
0           00:00:00.000:
1           00:00:00.000: 
2           00:00:00.000:
3           00:00:00.000:
4           00:00:00.000: 
... 
4943983    16:11:21.000: 
4943984    16:11:24.000:    
4943986    16:11:39.000:   
4943987    16:11:51.000:

Name: Time, Length: 4943988, dtype: object
```

​
I tried the below command . but It replaced all the values with nan.

```
timefmt = "%H:%M:%S"    

dadr['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(dadr['Time'], 
errors='coerce').dt.strftime(timefmt)
```

Output:

```
0         NaN    
1         NaN    
2         NaN    
3         NaN    
4         NaN     
       ..      
4943983   NaN      
4943984   NaN      
4943985   NaN     
4943986   NaN     
4943987   NaN     

Name: Time, Length: 4943988, dtype: float64
```

I would like to add that , there are timefields with non zero values in Seconds place .  such as time data '07:05:15.026:' does not match format '%H:%M:%S.000:' (match)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to put the `timefmt` to `format=` parameter in `pd.to_datetime`:

```
timefmt = "%H:%M:%S.000:"
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format=timefmt)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
       idx                Time
0  4943983 1900-01-01 16:11:21
1  4943984 1900-01-01 16:11:24
2  4943985 1900-01-01 16:11:38
3  4943986 1900-01-01 16:11:39
4  4943987 1900-01-01 16:11:51
```

---

EDIT: To parse the second fraction after `.`, you can use `%f`:

```
timefmt = "%H:%M:%S.%f:"
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format=timefmt)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
       idx                    Time
0  4943983 1900-01-01 16:11:21.100
1  4943984 1900-01-01 16:11:24.200
2  4943985 1900-01-01 16:11:38.300
3  4943986 1900-01-01 16:11:39.400
4  4943987 1900-01-01 16:11:51.500
```

Comment: Thank you . But My apologies that I failed to mention that there are non zero fields in seconds Field.  time data '07:05:15.026:' does not match format '%H:%M:%S.000:' (match)

Comment: why even suggest to parse with literal `.000` in the strptime directive?

Comment: Hi @AndrejKesely , Thank you , This worked but  I don't want the dates to display . that means  I want to remove the dates 1900-01-01 from the entire column. I want only the time

Comment: @vishnu Then you can convert the date back, for example: `print( df['Time'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S.%f') )`

Comment: Hi @AndrejKesely , when I do that , the format is back to Object datatype   todo['Time']= todo['Time'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S.%f')                                                #   Column      Dtype 
---  ------      ----- 
 0   Time        object

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
# build your dataset
times = [
'00:00:00.000:',
'16:11:21.000:',
'16:11:24.000:',
'16:11:38.000:',
'16:11:39.000:',
'16:11:51.000:'
]

# remove the last colon in your timestamps
times = [x.replace('000:','000') for x in times]

# create your dataset
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(times))

# perform your request
df['time'] = df[0].apply(lambda x: pd.Timestamp(x).strftime('%H:%M:%S.%f'))
```

Then you have:

[image]

Comment: Thank you . But My apologies that I failed to mention that there are non zero fields in seconds Field. time data '07:05:15.026:' does not match format '%H:%M:%S.000:' (match)

Comment: Hi , thank you  I am getting het error python-input-103-4c2ce6bff7e0> in <lambda>(x)
----> 1 roto['time'] = roto[0].apply(lambda x: pd.Timestamp(x).strftime('%H:%M:%S.%f'))

pandas\_libs\tslibs\timestamps.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp.__new__()

pandas\_libs\tslibs\conversion.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion.convert_to_tsobject()

pandas\_libs\tslibs\conversion.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion.convert_str_to_tsobject()

ValueError: could not convert string to Timestamp

Comment: Try this (change roto[0] for roto['time']):
roto['time'] = roto['time'].apply(lambda x: pd.Timestamp(x).strftime('%H:%M:%S.%f'))